# Let my menu repeat

Tags: html, css, graphics, menu, containers

I can't see how to make my menu repeat 100% out of the container, and still have the navigation menu center.

I want to ask to how to make a double border top and buttom on the menu.

[Here is the design](http://sijdesign.dk/rap/).

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: I don't really understand your question... can you expand a bit more?

Comment: For the double border use: `border-top:3px double red;border-bottom:3px double red;`

Comment: thanks, how do i make the menu repeat 100% http://d.pr/zVbl

Comment: do you mean the menu filling the 100% width of the navigation box?

Comment: more like repeat from left to right of the screen (browser) :), the double border how can i make the one red and another green? cause now the one is black :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote in the comments

> more like repeat from left to right of the screen (browser) :), the
>   double border how can i make the one red and another green? cause now
>   the one is black :/

If I understand correctly, you can do this in your css stylesheet

```
nav {
position: relative;
background-image: url(../img/menu.jpg);
width: 100%;
height: 79px;
border-top: 3px double red;  //CHANGE COLOR
border-bottom: 3px double green;    //CHANGE COLOR
top: 15px;
z-index: 2;
}
```